# How to use constructors as object keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I'm trying to construct a map of types and callbacks so I started with an structure like this:

```js
type Instantiable<T = unknown> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type SingleParamFn<TInput = unknown, TOuput = unknown> = (arg: TInput) => TOuput;

type TypesRecord<T> = { type: Instantiable<T>, callback: SingleParamFn<T> };
type TypesMap = TypesRecord[];   // This is the structure
```

An example of this:

```js
const myMap: TypesMap = [{ type: Date, callback: (value) => 'this is a Date' }];
```

This seems works as expected but I realised it is a bit inefficient as you need to loop the array to find the type you want.

I started to play with having the types as object keys and it seems to work at least in Google Chrome:

```js
class MyFancyObject {}
class MyOtherObject {}

const map = {
   [Date]: () => 'this is a date',
   [MyFancyObject]: () => 'this is a fancy object',
   [MyOtherObject]: () => 'this is another object'
};

console.log(map[Date]());           // 'this is a date'
console.log(map[MyFancyObject]());  // 'this is a fancy object'
console.log(map[MyOtherObject]());  // 'this is another object'

const obj = new MyFancyObject();
console.log(map[obj.constructor]());           // 'this is a fancy object'
console.log(map[(new Date()).constructor]());  // 'this is a date'
```

I've been checking some documentation and it seems like an object's key can only be an [string or a Symbol](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-object-type) so I checked what constitutes a Symbol and it seems to be a bit vage as it is defined as a [built-in object whose constructor returns a symbol primitive that's guaranteed to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) and an object's constructor is (to the best of my knowledge), unique.

Given all of this, is using the constructors as object keys a reliable approach? If so, how can I define the typescript type for such object? If it isn't, are there other options (like the `Map` object)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given all of this, is using the constructors as object keys a reliable approach?

No. As you said, an object's keys can only be strings or [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). A Symbol is a primitive you get from a property on `Symbol` (for well-known, specification-defined Symbols) or by calling `Symbol()` or `Symbol.for("...")`. Constructor functions are not symbols, they're functions.

Your `map` object's keys are strings. When you use a computed property name like `[MyFancyObject]`, if the value you provide is not a string or a Symbol (in your case, it's a function), it's converted to string implicitly as though you did `String(MyFancyObject)`. You can see that here:

```js
class MyFancyObject {}
class MyOtherObject {}

const map = {
   [Date]: () => 'this is a date',
   [MyFancyObject]: () => 'this is a fancy object',
   [MyOtherObject]: () => 'this is another object'
};

console.log(Object.keys(map));
console.log(map[MyFancyObject]());            // "this is a fancy object"
console.log(map["class MyFancyObject {}"]()); // also "this is a fancy object"
```

As you can see, the key you're thinking of as `MyFancyObject` is actually the string `"class MyFancyObject {}"`.

You *can* use constructor functions as keys in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), though:

```js
class MyFancyObject {}
class MyOtherObject {}

const map = new Map([
   [Date, () => 'this is a date'],
   [MyFancyObject, () => 'this is a fancy object'],
   [MyOtherObject, () => 'this is another object'],
]);

console.log(map.get(MyFancyObject)());
```

In that, the keys really are the constructor functions, not strings derived from them.